# Python TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, Django 3.1 CLOSED

Tags: python, django, api, python-requests, openweathermap

```
    city_info = {
    'city': city,
    'temp': res['main']['temp'],
    'weatherDescription': res['weather']['description'],
    'icon': res['weather']['icon'],
    'windSpeed': res['wind']['speed'],
}
```

Why when I call the 'weather' object of the OpenWetherMap API I have an error like:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am using Python 3.8.2 and Django 3.1

Full code, as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def index(request):
    # This is MINE API key! You can change it to yours, if you need it.
    apiKey = '8bf70752121d2f2366e66d73f3445966'
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=metric&appid=' + apiKey 

    city = 'Washington'
    res = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

    city_info = {
        'city': city,
        'temp': res['main']['temp'],
        'weatherDescription': res['weather']['description'],
        'icon': res['weather']['icon'],
        'windSpeed': res['wind']['speed'],
    }

    context = {'info': city_info}

    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

`res['weather']` is a list which contains a dictionary, So just do this instead:

```
city_info = {
    'city': city,
    'temp': res['main']['temp'],
    'weatherDescription': res['weather'][0]['description'],
    'icon': res['weather'][0]['icon'],
    'windSpeed': res['wind']['speed'],
}
```